# Was this Apache v2.4 configuration correct?

Tags: apache-2.4

I am using a VPS Server running on CentOS, Linux Platform.
Recently some two to three before the VPS server starts behaving strangely.

I am using Google Analytics to track down the visitors. Take one hour time as an example.
The live visitors to the site was about 50+ and everything seems fine, suddenly for no reason, the live visitors starts falling to less than 15.
After 2 - 5 minutes, it starts to rise again to 40+, sometimes goes above 50.
Then, again the traffic starts falling.

This cycle repeats 5 - 6 times every hour which causes a huge fall in the 24hr traffic. I asked the hosting team and they said the server is fine with enough resources to handle even more traffic.

Here are the following specs for Apache.

```
Start Servers: 8
Minimum Spare Servers: 8
Maximum Spare Servers: 16
Server Limit: 256
Max Request Workers: 250
Max Connections Per Child: 2500
Keep-Alive Timeout: 10
Max Keep-Alive Requests: 300
Timeout: 60
```

One Wordpress site is hosted which is getting 5000 unique visitors every day. But the Apache server struggling to serve more than 25 visitors constantly.
There are heavy fluctuations occurring every hour, sometimes the live visitors grow more than 50+ and fall after 2 - 3 minutes to less than 20.
After 10 minutes, the cycle repeats. 
I tested average server load which is very normal, 98% CPU is idle always.
How to tune Apache to serve requests constantly 40+(Approx)?

Comment: If CPU is not the problem, what about memory? Check it with `free`. And load average? `cat /proc/loadavg`. If your CPU is almost idle, the first three numbers should be below 1. And where is the database located? You may also check blocked processes `ps uxawr`, that might help you find what's stuck. There's just too many things that can cause this.

Comment: Thank you sir, 
Here are the Ram Details: Total: 6GB Used: 5.6GB
Free: 372 MB
Load average: 0.49 0.21 0.09

Result ps uxawr

USER       PID %CPU %MEM    VSZ   RSS TTY      STAT START   TIME COMMAND
root     13108  3.0  0.0 108328  1920 pts/0    R+   08:24   0:00 ps uxawr

Do you need any more details sir?

Comment: @MyilRaj don't add additional details in comments, they are unreadable there. Edit your question and add the information there.